# Having trouble updating list members on subclass of dict

Tags: python-3.x

I'm developing a custom dict implementation. The current implementation for the CustomDict class that I have is [this](https://gitlab.com/vandraren/customDict/-/blob/f60f799fd0f3f5ba914aef75e28b0bb9a2939517/customDict/main.py).

It all goes well and good for reading and even updating some of the attributes, but when it's time to access list members by index, it stops updating correctly as if a copy was being fleshed out.

Here's an [issue](https://gitlab.com/vandraren/customDict/-/issues/1) on the repo for more details on how to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple. On the constructor, I need to set the dict key as well like this:

```
for key, value in kwargs.items():
    attr = self.__get_attr(name=key, data=value)
    self.__setattr__(key, attr)
    self[key] = attr
```

This way, both elements are linked and the update is fully visible